# How to find row in DB2 .DEL file by identifier from LOAD log file

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to load data into DB2 for LUW table from .DEL file previously exported with EXPORT command:

```
LOAD CLIENT FROM f:\file.del OF DEL messages f:\file.log insert INTO sch.tab
```

Got some rows rejected. Trying to find problem data by log file but do not understand how to find exact row having messages like this:

> SQL3120W  The field value in row "F29-841936" and column "1" cannot be
>   converted to an INTEGER value, but the target column is not nullable. 
>   The row  was not loaded.

Comment: There will be another message in the output that says something along the lines of "Row F29-841936 corresponds to line 19849 of the file".

Comment: Ian, I did not find anything alike in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with EOL (ASCII code 10 or 13) symbols occured inside of VARCHAR or CHAR fields. The solution was to use DELPRIORITYCHAR modifier.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD has concepts and options for a dumpfile (see `MODIFIED BY DUMPFILE`) and exception table (see option `FOR EXCEPTION`). 
In your case with a format mismatch these rows would be dumped into the dumpfile as they cannot be loaded into the given table structure.
If you get rejects because of duplicate keys these rows would be sent to the defined exeption table.

Check out the [LOAD](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html?lang=en) documentation for details.